# How do i save the contents of a table to a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to save the contents of a table to a cookie, I have a table that is content-editable and I want to save the data to a cookie so later i can load the data back into the table

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code you have tried so far in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You only get 4093 bytes worth of cookies **per** domain.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie can only store text, so you have to convert your table to some kind of text format and store it. Two of the most used are **JSON** and **Base64**, you cant easily find examples about them on the web.